# looping image with tcpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I used following code to loop image through the pdf file, It is working correctly only for first pdf page, up to second page it prints one image per page. why is that?

```
$this->load->helper('directory'); 
$dir = "assets/barcode/"; 
$map = directory_map($dir);

$this->load->library("Pdf");
$pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', false, 'UTF-8', true);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12, '', true);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(20);
$pdf->setFooterMargin(20);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,0);


$pdf->AddPage();

$x = 0;
$y = 0;
foreach($map as $k) {

    $pdfimage = "assets/barcode/".$k;
    $pdfimgname = $k;
    $pdf->Image($pdfimage, 30, 25 + $x, 0, 0, '', '', '', false, 9);        

    $pdf->SetXY(70, 30 + $y);
    $pdf->writeHTML($pdfimgname,100 , 30, 0, 0, '', '', '', false, 9);

    $x = $x + 30;
    $y = $y + 30;

}           
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: It's either the limit of `$map` has been reached or it's getting the current y-axis wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My requirement is to create a pdf of generated QrCodes. I write this logic. Hope this will help you.

```
/**
 * @param {array} $generated : This is array of qr code images
 */
function tcpdfun($generated)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $your_width = 304.8;
    $your_height = 457.2;
    $custom_layout = array($your_width, $your_height);

    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, $custom_layout, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    $pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 4);

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->setJPEGQuality(100);

    $startX = 8.8; // X-axis margin
    $startY = 6.8; // Y-axis margin
    $qrPath = base_url()."qrs/"; // QrCode Images folder
    $imgHW = 25; // Image Height-Width - Square
    $gap = 4; // Gap between two images

    $j = 1;

    for($i=0; $i < count($generated); $i++, $j++)
    {
        $pdf->setXY($startX, $startY); // set XY axis
        $startX = $startX+$imgHW;  // Add image width

        $border = array('LTRB' => array('width' => 0.2, 'cap' => 'butt',
            'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(190, 190, 190)));  // image border

        $pdf->Image($qrPath.$generated[$i]["qr_code"].'.png', '', '', $imgHW, $imgHW, 'PNG', '', 'T',
                        false, 300, '', false, false, $border, false, false, false);  // image print in pdf

        if($j > 0) { $pdf->setXY($startX - $imgHW + 1.5, $startY+$imgHW); }
        else { $pdf->setXY($startX + 1.5, $startY+$imgHW); }

        $pdf->Write(1, $generated[$i]["qr_code"], '',false, '', false, 0, false, false, 0, 0, '');

        /** I calculate my page size and come to know that I can print only 11 images in a row, 
        so I write the following logic to reset X axis to initial position and add an extra height to Y axis **/

        if($j >= 11)
        {
            $startY = $startY+$imgHW+$gap;
            $startX = 8.8;
            $j = 0;
        }

        /** I calculate my page size and come to know that I can print only 165 images per page, 
        so I write following logic to add new page after 165 images, and reset X-Y axis to initial position on new page. **/

        if( (($i+1)%165) == 0 && $i!=0)
        {
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $startX = 8.8;
            $startY = 6.8;
            $j = 0;
        }
    }

    $file_name = "qrbatch_".date("YmdHis").".pdf";
    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output($file_name, 'D');
}
```

I wrote lot of comments over there for better understanding, but you need to modify the logic in terms of number as per your images size requirements.